# SQL Server Log Shipping: File copy options?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, disaster-recovery

I usually use redgate sql backup which has a transaction log copy mechanism built in.

If I roll my own log shipping, what are established ways to move the log file?

I want to emphasize: The way log shipping works in the log shipping feature is a mess. The requirement of a file share, and all the firewall and auth overhead of that are simply over the top.

In my dreams, there would be an automatic way to do log shipping via azure files. Click click click. Think how great this would be:

1) No file shares needed!
2) Your backups and tran logs are automatically backed up in azure cloud (DR step #1 !)
3) The remote can be anywhere
4) I can now easily do one-to-many log shipping, because the point to point architecture of the built in log shipping is side stepped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirement as a component for our Disaster Recovery solution.  Due to security and policy reasons, it was not possible to use regular Log Shipping.

We ended up transferring the logs via Linux servers and rsync, and implementing the Log Backup restore using a small application which can be found at https://github.com/kervinpierre/mssqlapplylogs

Comment: This is not the log shipping of my dreams, but it is close! We are getting a lot closer to using azure , with the new file share function of azure. Then we can use encrypted backups and log backups, pushed to azure via robocopy, then pulled form azure with robocopy, and use your script to apply them.

Answer (score 2):

> If I roll my own log shipping, what are established ways to move the log file?

**Why do you want to roll out your own logshipping solution ?** Microsoft has put in a lot of effort for giving out-of-box Logshipping from SQL 2005 and up. This is tested by millions of customers since sql 2005, so highly unlikely you will encounter any bugs with it.

You can refer to : [Step By Step SQL Server Log Shipping](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2301/step-by-step-sql-server-log-shipping/) for how to configure native logshipping.

References for Custom Logshipping :

- [Log shipping and A Control Mechanism](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Log+Shipping/70506/)
- [Custom Log Shipping](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/customlogshipping/1201/)
- [How to Setup Log Shipping for Multiple Databases](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Log+Shipping/75042/)

Using Powershell :

- [Log Shipping via PowerShell Invoke-LSRestore](http://www.techtree.co.uk/sql-server/log-shipping-via-powershell-invoke-lsrestore/)
- [Your poor man’s SQL Server log shipping-PowerShell version](http://bassplayerdoc.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/your-poor-mans-sql-server-log-shipping-powershell-version/)
- [Secure Log Shipping via SSL FTP](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/merrill_aldrich/archive/2011/05/19/case-study-secure-log-shipping-via-ssl-ftp.aspx)
- [Automating SQL Log Shipping over SFTP (SSH), the simple way](http://www.serverside-developer.com/2012/09/automating-sql-log-shipping-over-sftp.html)

Comment: Why roll my own log shipping? Because the built in mechanism requires a file share. I am now shipping to TWO destinations, one via Azure blob storage, the other via file system... gotsta roll my own.... (MS native doesnt have anything useful for log shipping over azure)

Comment: `I am now shipping to TWO destinations, one via Azure blob storage, the other via file system... gotsta roll my own` you did not mention anything about azure in your question :-)